# Recover image from google chrome's cache

Tags: google-chrome

I tried searching this online myself, almost all article/posts talks about the cache directory at the following location:

`C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\`

I don't see any `cache` directory at that location. The only cache related directory I see there is `Media Cache` and `GPU Cache`.

I also tried to use http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html this also is not able to find the directory it points me to Opera cache directory instead.

And I tried: `chrome://cache/` there I found the link of the image but I only see binary HTTP headers, I don't see any binary file content.

I'm using Windows 10.

Is there any way to recover the image I viewed before?